# Room composite Primary Key link to Foreign Key

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, primary-key, android-room

I am implementing an android application with Room database and have a small question about relationships in this DB.

I have two tables:

```
@Entity(tableName = "foods", primaryKeys = {"id", "language_id"},
        indices = {@Index(value = {"id", "language_id"}, unique = true)},
        inheritSuperIndices = true)
public class Food {

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private String mId;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "language_id")
    private String mLanguageId;

}

@Entity(tableName = "ingredients", primaryKeys = {"id", "language_id"},
        indices = {@Index(value = {"id", "language_id"}, unique = true), 
        @Index(value = {"food_id", "food_language_id"}, unique = true)},
        foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = Food.class, parentColumns ="id", 
        childColumns = "food_id", onUpdate = CASCADE, onDelete = CASCADE),
        @ForeignKey(entity = Food.class, parentColumns = "language_id", 
        childColumns = "food_language_id", onUpdate = CASCADE, onDelete = 
        CASCADE)},
        inheritSuperIndices = true)
public class Ingredient {

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private String mId;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "language_id")
    private String mLanguageId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "food_id")
    private String mFoodId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "food_language_id")
    private String mFoodLanguageId;

}
```

The both tables 'Food' and 'Ingredient' have composite primary keys ('id', 'language_id'). The Food object has to contains a List and of course   a @Relationship

```
public class FoodWithIngredients extends Food{

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "food_id", entity = 
    Ingredient.class)
    private List<Ingredient> mIngredients;

}
```

After I try to run this code received these messages

**Warnning:**

> food_language_id column references a foreign key but it is not part of
>   an index. This may trigger full table scans whenever parent table is
>   modified so you are highly advised to create an index that covers this
>   column.

**Error:**

```
Ingredient has a foreign key (food_id) that references Food (id) but Food does not have a unique index on those columns nor the columns are its primary key. SQLite requires having a unique constraint on referenced parent columns so you must add a unique index to Food that has (id) column(s).
```

Could someone help me with that?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found where was my mistake. My @ForeignKey was wrong, the right one is this:

```
@ForeignKey(
             entity = Food.class,
             parentColumns = {"id", "language_id"},
             childColumns = {"food_id", "food_language_id"},
             onUpdate = CASCADE, onDelete = CASCADE)
```

The difference is that I put multiple columns inside 'parentColumns' and 'childColumns' and it works correct.

@Danail Alexiev The insertion is something like this:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertFoods(List<Food> foods);

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertIngredients(List<Ingredient> ingredients);

@Transaction
public void insertFoodData(List<Food> foods, RulesOfGolfDatabase database) {
    if (foods != null && database != null) {
        insertFoods(foods);
        for (Food food : foods) {
            insertIngredients(food.getIngrediants());
        }
    }
}
```

The most important thing here is that you have to insert first the owner of the @Relation (In this example is Food) and after that every data which is in the relationship

Comment: What is this: `RulesOfGolfDatabase database`? It seems you are not using it