# Kotlin Android Room Composite primary key many to many relation

Tags: kotlin, many-to-many, android-room, composite-primary-key

I have got two tables: equipment and location. Equipment table has composite primary key consisted of columns "component_id", "id". Location table has primary key "id".

**Could you show me the way how to create many to many relationship in room with composite key?**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "equipment", primaryKeys = ["component_id", "id"],
)
data class EquipmentModel(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "component_id") val componentId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "location_id") val locationId: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "stocktaking_sheet_id") val stocktakingSheetId: Int,
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "label_exchange_demanded") val labelExchangeDemanded: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "photo_path") val photoPath: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "noticed_amount") val noticedAmount: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "expected_amount") val expectedAmount: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bar_code") val barCode: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rfid_code") val RfidCode: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "construction_number") val serialNumber: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "stocktaking_number") val stocktakingNumber: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "external_number") val externalNumber: String,
    val remarks: String
)
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "location")
data class LocationModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "building_id") val buildingId: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "organizational_unit_id") val organizationalUnitId: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "use_place_id") val usePlaceId: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "facility_id") val facilityId: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "building_name") val buildingName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cell_name") val cellName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "use_place_name") val usePlaceName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "facility_name") val facilityName: String,
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50350741/14162959

Comment: Why do you have `component_id` as part of the primary key?

Comment: Because there can be a few equipments with same id, but with other componentId. This is must have assumption.